# GOOGLE SHEETS // How many time is this word mentioned in a cell?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Happy new year in advance.

I want to make an if statement that can determines how many times is this text has been mentioned in this cell.

Example:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AF1K.png)

I want an if statement that returns 1 if "hi" is mentioned 3 times or more in this cell.

im working with this `=if(REGEXMATCH('Raw data'!L2,"(CC)|(EC)|(BC)|(NC)"),"Failed","Passed")`

and i want to return failed if (NC) is mentioned 5 times or more.

thank you!

already mentioned ...

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT('Raw data'!L2, " "), "hi"))
```

[image]

---

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT('Raw data'!L2, " "), 
 "\(CC|EC|BC|NC\)"))<=5, "pass", "fail")
```

[image]